# print some separator for every sliding window in Flink streaming data

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to print the separator for every sliding window in Flink streaming data.
For instance, this is the [wordcount example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/windowing/WindowWordCount.java) of Flink which prints counted words in the last 10 seconds with 5 second step.
If it runs correctly, at first, should print a single window after 10 seconds  like,

```
(love,2)
(test,10)
(hope,5)
(dead,2)
(evil,5)
```

and every 5 seconds, additional output(sliding windows) are appended to existed one

```
(love,2)
(test,10)
(hope,5)
(dead,2)
(evil,5)
(love,15)
(test,2)
(hope,4)
(dead,6)
(evil,10)
```

But I want to make these output distinguishable of each windows.

```
-------------------------------------------------
(love,2)
(test,10)
(hope,5)
(dead,2)
(evil,5)
-------------------------------------------------
(love,15)
(test,2)
(hope,4)
(dead,6)
(evil,10)
------------------------------------------------
... And So On
```

Seems like it doesn't help to add some transformation function to `DataStream` variable to print separator (i.e.`apply()`,`map()`, etc).

Just using single `System.out.println` does not solve problem because it prints only once at the start of `DataStream`'s data flow.

How can I implement this idea?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. A 10 seconds sliding window with 5 seconds step means that Flink generates a 10 seconds window every 5 seconds, which will be pruned after the watermark exceeds the window's end time.

Comment: @JiayiLiao (Sliding) windows will be pruned and printed continuously for every 5 seconds. But when Flink print windows, usually it prints 'pruned' windows consecutively in stdout such (window1)(window2).. But these output are not easily distinguishable because it is not easy to find which record is the part of which window. So I want to print some separators (e.g. '-------' bar type) for recognizing each windows in every 'pruning time'.

Comment: Try WindowFunction and output the separators mannually.